# Resetting AUTO_INCREMENT primary key

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql

I have a table with a primary key used as a foreign key in another table, now when I delete the entry the primary keys do not stay in order and I want to reorder them and also want to maintain integrity of foreign key

Comment: In what way it is even related to wordpress? please edit your question and include all wordpress relevant information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1

Change 1 to your desired value. for that case prior to execution of this you can sort your table with the primary field and get the highest value.